# VBA Group Column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create VBA code to group columns by defined column numbers, however, I get a Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error on `ws.Columns(i.ColumnToGroup).Columns.Group`. How can I fix it?

This is the code:

```vb
Sub AutoOutlineData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim BegColumn As Integer
    Dim LastColumn As Integer
    Dim ColumnToGroup As Integer

    BegColumn = Application.InputBox("Please input begin column number", "BeginColumNum", "", Type:=1)
    'Type 1 is a number
    ColumnToGroup = Application.InputBox("Please input column number each gropuing", "NumberOfGrouping", "", Type:=1)
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
        LastColumn = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        ws.Cells.ClearOutline
        For i = BegColumn To LastColumn Step ColumnToGroup
            ws.Columns(i, ColumnToGroup).Columns.Group
        Next i
    Set ws = Nothing
 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess as to what you want to do:

```
ws.Columns(i).Resize(,ColumnToGroup).Group
```

However I think it will create one continuous group.